# How to allow access to PHP methods according to user's role?

Tags: php, model, rbac

I have a basic User model that satisfies all the needs of a generic user. I now need to create several different roles for the user, each with about 10-20 different methods that are unusable by the other roles.

Assume that I have to load the generic User class to determine the user's role...

Since it's inefficient and heavy to package so many different role-based methods into the generic User model (when they can't be utilized by all roles), what is the best way to give user's access to their role-based methods ONLY when they need them?

Here are some ideas I'm tossing around:

1. Have a separate class of services per role, and give them to the User class according to the user's role
2. Simply lug around all the methods in the user class, and only allow access to each when the user has the correct role.
3. Totally refactor and make the role based classes inherit from the User class.

Are any of these good ideas, or is there a better idea at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just composition the role based classes into the User object?

```
$user = new User(/* pass role as an arg */);

// Internally:
// if ($user->getRole() instanceof AdminRole) or similar...
if ($user->isAdmin()) {
    // AdminRole::doSomethingAdminish()
    $user->getRole()->doSomethingAdminish();
}
```

Comment: So, in this case - I would instantiate the User(), and depending on the role, the User class would "instantiate" the roles, which could then be used like so - $user->adminRoles->doSomething() ?

Comment: I edited the answer to explain it a little more clearly.  Essentially, you're separating the "role" and "user" concepts, instead of trying to bundle them into an inheritance chain.

Comment: Ah I see, so the "role" in this case is simply a set of "helper" functions that are "given" to the class if the user fits the description...sounds pretty flexible, and I like the separation

Comment: Correct.  And if it's desirable for you, you could also structure it so Users can have multiple roles simply by using an array of Roles, instead of one Role.  This would likely cause headaches in an inheritance-based design, since PHP classes can only extend one class.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure if your specific example is how I am going to do it in the end (basically, instead of passing in the role, i'll have the class generate it, itself), but the general concept seems to work for me. :)

Comment: No problem.  I only suggested passing the Role instead of having the User constructor create it because it's much easier to unit test that way.  Happy coding. :)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the factory pattern. Essentially, you pass it the data required to instantiate the object, and it returns the correct object in a ready to use state.

Perhaps something like

```
class UserFactory
{
   public static function getUser($userId)
   {
      $user = new User($userId);
      switch ($user->getType()) {
         case 'admin' :
            return new AdminUser($user);
         case 'guest' :
            return new GuestUser($user);
         default :
            //handle 
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the response...in this case does getUser() retrieve the user's data from the db? and are AdminUser and GuestUser extensions of User?

Comment: OH, I think I get it...does that mean I would do something like: $admin = new UserFactory(12); echo $admin->user->user_id; ....if i wanted to get to the generic user object?